# How to check if user exists in mysql database vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have some code to read from a mysql database but I was just wondering how i can modify this to see if a user exists in the table?

thanks

```
    Private Sub GetDBData()
    Try
        'prepare connection query 
        strQuery = "SELECT users.Username, users.Password " & _
        "FROM users " & _
        "WHERE Username='User'"
        SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
        'open db and start query
        dbCon.Open()
        DR = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
        While DR.Read
            MysqlData.Text = MysqlData.Text & DR.Item("Username") & Space(10) & DR.Item("Password") & vbCrLf
        End While
        'done so closing db
        DR.Close()
        dbCon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: At a glance, please use parameterized SQL. You're wide open for SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to make a query like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE Username='user123';
```

You run it, take back the value it returns and if it is 0 then the users doesn't exist. If it is 1 then he exists and if it is bigger than 1 then something is wrong (you have more than one users with the same username).

Answer (score 2):

My VB's pretty rusty but here's the gist of it;

```
Private Sub GetDBData()
Try
    'prepare connection query 
    strQuery = "SELECT users.Username, users.Password " & _
    "FROM users " & _
    "WHERE Username='User'"
    SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
    'open db and start query
    dbCon.Open()
    DR = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

    If DR.HasRows Then

        While DR.Read
            MysqlData.Text = MysqlData.Text & DR.Item("Username") & Space(10) & DR.Item("Password") & vbCrLf
        End While
    Else
        'COMMENT: Your user didn't exist
    End If

    'done so closing db

    'COMMENT: move to a finally() section and check objects are not null before closing
    DR.Close()
    dbCon.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

Use `command`with `parameters` to avoid SQL Injection. An strategy for that *if you are only checking for username existence with doing some comparison* is to create a function which returns boolean. Below is an example code based on your needs.

```
Private Function IsUserExist(userName as string) AS Boolean

        Dim returnValue as boolean = false

        strQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*)"
        strQuery &= "FROM users "
        strQuery &= "WHERE Username = @xUserName "

        Using xConn as new MySQLCnnection("connectionStringHere")
            Using xComm as New MySQLCommand()
                With xComm
                    .Connection = xConn
                    .CommandText = strQuery
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@xUserName", userName)
                End With
                Try
                    xConn.Open()
                    If CInt(xComm.ExecuteScalar()) > 0 Then
                        returnValue = true
                    End If
                Catch ex as MySQlException
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                    returnValue = false
                Finally
                    xConn.Close
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using

        return returnValue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify it? Too much wrong with that.
No using block, exception swallowing, and potential sql injection attack.

Something like (I don't do VB but the basic idea is sound)

```
Private Function UserExists(argUser As string) As Bool
  strQuery = "SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username=?User"
  Using SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
    SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("?User",argUser)  
    dbCon.Open()
    Using reader = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader()
      return reader.Read()
    End Using
  End Using
End Function
```

I'd be instantiating a connection as well instead of getting it from whereever you are currently (in a using block) as well if it were me.

Comment: Parameterised query Effectively ?User will be replaced with the value argument in SQLCmd.Parameters.Add call, in a way that doesn't open you up to a sql injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub btnlogin_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myData As MySqlDataReader
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=name;User ID=root;Password=pwd;")

    Dim loginstring As String = "SELECT uname,password,type FROM logindetails WHERE uname = '" + txtuname.Text + "' AND password = '" + txtpwd.Text + "' "
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException 'If it fails do this... (i.e. no internet connection, etc.)
        MsgBox("Error connecting to database. Check your internet connection.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try

    myCommand.Connection = conn
    myCommand.CommandText = loginstring
    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
    myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader

    If myData.HasRows = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Credentials", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Adminhome.aspx")
        MsgBox("Logged in as " & txtuname.Text & ".", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple...

Before you go into your while loop declare an integer and set it to zero. In the while loop before you start getting your data, set that integer to one. Outside the while but before the catch, put an if statement to inform you when the integer is still zero meaning there was no data in the db. Something like this...

```
Private Sub GetDBData()
    Try
        'prepare connection query 
        strQuery = "SELECT users.Username, users.Password " & _
        "FROM users " & _
        "WHERE Username='User'"
        SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
    'open db and start query
    dbCon.Open()
        DR = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        While DR.Read
        x = 1
        MysqlData.Text = MysqlData.Text & DR.Item("Username") & Space(10) & DR.Item("Password") & vbCrLf
    End While
    'done so closing db

    DR.Close()
    dbCon.Close()

   if x = 0
        Messagebox.Show("Record not found")
   End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

End Sub